# Is there a number of days limit with MIN_TIMESTAMP and MAX_TIMESTAMP in the Instagram API?

Tags: instagram

I'm using the Instagram API GET/users/user-id/media/recent to get photos between certain dates though not all photos come back if the number of days between the dates is quite long. Is there a number of days limit for MIN_TIMESTAMP and MAX_TIMESTEP?

Couldn't find anything in the documentation but I'm sure I read somewhere that it was 14 days?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram API has a hard limit of returning 20 posts per request. To get more posts between certain dates you can start by requesting a feed with the MAX_TIMESTAMP parameter and then move backwards in time by 20 posts at a time using the `next_url` which is in the `pagination` object returned by your request. Do this until a post is older than MIN_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Thanks for that - I'll give that a go. Strangely though I'm getting more than 20 posts back.